# Null comparison

Tags: java

I saw this piece of code today and wanted to know is there a difference between

```
return (null==employeeName ? "": employeeName);
```

and

```
return (employeeName == null ? "": employeeName);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not anymore.

It used to be the case, in the wild days of C and C++ that non-boolean expressions, were OK in if statements, so that there would be no difference, unless you made a classic programmer mistake and forgot an equals sign:

```
employee = null
```

would compile, but

```
null = employee
```

would not.

This doesn't matter in Java, because an Employee type isn't a boolean, and the compiler, rather than the syntax, stops you from shooting yourself in the foot; but whoever wrote that was probably in the habit from their days of writing C.

Comment: And of course this being Java (not C++), you'll get a compiler error.  Java won't allow assignment in a conditional.

Comment: The first will not compile, but not because it's an assignment.  It's because the type of the assignment expression isn't a boolean.  If it was an assignment to a boolean it would compile.

Comment: I know.. I mention that it doesn't matter in Java, but I'm making a historical point. I'll edit to clarify

Answer (score 1):

No difference.  Just a different order of writing the operands.  Personally I'd prefer the second one.

Answer (score 0):

No difference, both are the same in terms of returning the result. But I prefer

```
return (employeeName == null ? "": employeeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is common, and not same.

```
//This is safe against null employeeName:  
return ("".equals(employeeName) ? "": employeeName);


return (employeeName.equals("") ? "": employeeName);
```

Comment: @sje397, if `employeeName` is `null`, the second one will throw a `NullPointerException`. The first one will not. I think thats what he meant by _safe against null_

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but this is kind of a funny example.  In both cases the statement should just be `return employeeName`.  Your choice of return values confuses the issue a bit.

Comment: @Nivas - I didn't mean to compare these two, but I was talking about the first one here vs. the code in the question (which is also 'safe against null').

Answer (score 0):

both are the same, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is a classical *coding standard* that while doing any comparisons between constants and variables or literals and variables, the constant/literal should be on the left hand side.

So when you want to check whether `status` is `COMPLETE`, it was recommended to do it this way:

```
if("COMPLETE".equals(status))
{
}
```

The advantage here is that a null check on status was not required. doing the *normal* way: `if(status.equals("COMPLETES"))` will throw a `NullPointerException` if status were null.

In my opinion, this is more of a programming style. I find the *normal* way more readable even with an extra null check:

```
if(status != null && status.equals("COMPLETES"))
```

And a missing null check should anyway be found by a good unit test suite.